# C# Ef Core Linq Query adding a calculated field to existing query results without using model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

Given the following code which displays a list of fields from a model that has over 300 fields in it:

```
Foo = await
    (
      _context.Foo
        .Where(r => !StatusExceptionList.Contains(r.Status))
        .Where(r => (Convert.ToDateTime(r.date) - today).TotalDays < 31)
        .Where(r => r.Pid == PId)                   
    )
    .Union
    (
    _context.Foo
        .Where(r => !DraftStatusExceptionList.Contains(r.Status))
        .Where(r => r.Pid == PId)
        .Where(r => r.Csstatus != "NA" || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Csstatus))
        .Where(r => !_context.Foo
                    .Where(rr => rr.Pid == PersonId)
                    .Select(rr => rr.Fooid)                 
                    .Contains(r.Fooid)
              )
    )
    .ToListAsync();
```

Would it be possible to add a virtual field with a static value of 0 to the records in one side of the union and a value of 1 to the records on the other side of the union and then finally sort by the virtual field contents?

The idea is that the top part of the union displays in order first and then under that, the second part of the union is displayed.

The below example is how I see it in my mind and it's not working, but something along the lines of using an anon type, but with a * to grab all fields from the model its being inserted into -

```
Foo = await
    (
      _context.Foo
        .Where(r => !StatusExceptionList.Contains(r.Status))
        .Where(r => (Convert.ToDateTime(r.date) - today).TotalDays < 31)
        .Where(r => r.Pid == PId)                   
        .Select(rr => new
           {
               * //all fields that exist in r already need to be represented as well as the virtual field 'sortvalue'.....
               SortValue = 0
           });
    )
    .Union
    (
    _context.Foo
        .Where(r => !DraftStatusExceptionList.Contains(r.Status))
        .Where(r => r.Pid == PId)
        .Where(r => r.Csstatus != "NA" || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Csstatus))
        .Where(r => !_context.Foo
                    .Where(rr => rr.Pid == PersonId)
                    .Select(rr => rr.Fooid)                 
                    .Contains(r.Fooid)
              )
        .Select(rrr => new
           {
               * //all fields that exist in r/rr already need to be represented as well as the virtual field 'sortvalue'.....
               SortValue = 1
           });
    )
    //...insert ordering logic here that uses sortValue to show the top query contents first, followed by the bottom queries contents
    .OrderBy(r => sortValue);
    .ToListAsync();
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you create Foo subclass containing the property and then map it using AutoMapper?

Comment: are you actually trying to assign row numbers, is that what sortvalue is?

Comment: Hi there, I updated the code a little bit. I'm actually using a union but was trying to simplify the question. I guess that probably wasn't the best approach. What I want to do is assign a flag to all records that come from the top query in the union to 0 and a 1 for all records that come from the bottom query in the union. Then I want to sort on flag to display the top union's query results at the top of the page and the bottom union's query results under them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a example using the northwind db.  An anonymous type is used to keep track of which part of the union the result came from.  The result is then ordered using the discriminator o, then select is used to convert back to the original type.

```
var users = db.Employees
    .Where(emp => emp.FirstName == "Nancy")
    .Select(emp => new { emp, o = 0 })
    .Union( db.Employees
        .Where(emp => emp.City == "Seattle")
        .Select(u => new { emp, o = 1 })
        )
    .OrderBy(u => u.o)
    .Select(u => u.emp);
```